# Swinject giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 2 within a simple project. Working if compiled with Xcode 9 beta

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exc-bad-access, swinject

I have a [minimal working project](https://github.com/kerry/SwinjectBug) which if compiled with Xcode 8.3.3 gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The project is a simple VIPER implementation of modules. Swinject is being used to create the module itself along with all the dependencies.

How I solved the problem (or thought I solved):

1. By removing references of the SwinjectBug directory and re-adding solved the problem a few days ago. However, this is not working anymore.

What still solves the problem:

1. Compiling and running in Xcode 9-beta with the same iPhone model and iOS version works perfectly. [This observation was probably wrong. Not working all the time]
2. If I force cast `output as! SplashScreenPresenter`, the code works fine.

Possible scenarios:

1. There is a bug in Xcode 8.3.3 which is solved in Xcode 9
   But if the above is true, it should have failed for other modules but that is not the case.
2. Something is wrong in the way I am using Swinject.

You may compile and run the project.

I am using:

1. iOS 10.3.1 on iPhone 6s 64GB
2. Xcode 8.3.3

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs in SplashViewController on calling viewIsReady on output

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    output.viewIsReady()
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the part of the code causing the problem?

Comment: @YoichiTagaya the complete github project is also linked in the question

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. If you can point out the problem, it's appreciated. I'll try looking through the project later when I have time.

Comment: The problem is that when I run the project, it gives me EXC_BADD_ACCESS in the above mentioned line of code. The problem arises in a special case of implementing VIPER architecture wherein we have a Base module and every other module is inheriting from it. By the way, the problem will be clear only when you go through the small project. I have found a work around for now so you may have a look at the project whenever you get time. Thanks @YoichiTagaya